# difference between getting location by using LocationListener and getLastLocation() in FusedLocationApi

Tags: api, location

i use **FusedLocationApi** to get user's location and send back to server periodically. as google shown in [Google I/O 2013](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Bte_GHuxUGc),this approach can get position even under **in-door environment**. but in my experience, this is not really work well. two questions:

1. how FusedLocationApi get location while enter in-door environment
   without gps and Wi-Fi? i found it using network provider, this
   approach with very low accuracy. doesn't it using g-sensor or gyro?
2. what's the difference between getting location by using
   LocationListener(aware location change continuously) and getLastLocation()(get last location while timer triggered),which approach has higher accuracy?

thanks all~